# Intermixing of signed and unsigned variables

Tags: c

I tried this example below to find out the security issues in C due to the intermixing of signed and unsigned numbers.

In the code below, I could not understand how the corruption happens here due to the length having a negative value.

The read() will try to read the loc -1 of the file. So is there a overflow because of this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int fd;

int get_length(){
    fd = open("hello.txt",O_RDWR);
    return -1;
}

int read_data(){
    int length,n;
    char buffer[1024];
    printf("\n read_data() \n");
    length = get_length();
    if(length > 1024){
        perror("\n Big file! \n");
        return 0;
    }
    //printf("\n %d \n",length);
    read(fd,buffer,length);
    printf("\n %s \n",buffer);
    return length;
}

int main(){
    read_data();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't try to read location `-1`. It will attempt to read `(2^32)-1` bytes from the file and will overflow `buffer` if the size of the file is > `1024`. `n` and `length` are at risk of being overwritten and likely other things leading to a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd argument to `read` is `size_t` which is unsigned. -1 is encoded as 0xFFFFFFFF (or 0xFFFFFFFE on rare machines) on a 32 bit machine. When you passed a "small" negative integer to an unsigned integer, you will get a very large value. These lines are equivalent

```
read(fd,buffer,-1);
```

and

```
read(fd,buffer,(unsigned long)-1);
```

and

```
read(fd,buffer,0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Comment: "1 is encoded as 0xFFFFFFFF on a 32 bit machine" - well, on a 32-bit machine with 2's complement representation for signed numbers.

Comment: @H2CO3 - the question of non-2's complement machines came up before. Yes, there are some (most are obsolete), but chances are if you are using one right now, you aren't asking newbie questions like this on stack overflow. Even so, a negative value on a 1's complement machine is still a large positive value when cast to `unsigned` (0xFFFFFFFE).